# Is there have a way to delay type binding at code level in C++?

Tags: c++, auto

I'm going to request some user configuration via json from the server that contains two types of data like (`usrID`, `bool`), and (`usrID`, `int`). so, I created two map to classify and reload two functions with the same name to put the data into the corresponding map after parsed.

For the sake of refinement, I used the `auto` keyword of C++11 to initialize a variable without assign and determined its type whether bool or int mentioned above through assigned by parse function, so as to call the overloaded function directly to store them.
But it causes compiler error that cannot use a auto variable without assign.

```
bool fromStringtoBool() {……}
int  fromStringtoInt() {……}

void setAppidConfig(int,bool);
void setAppidConfig(int,int);
……
……
void main func()
{
    ……
    int usrId;
    auto value;
    if(isBool())
    {
       value = fromStringtoBool();
    }
    else
    {
       value = fromStringtoInt();
    }

    setAppidConfig(usrId,value)
    ……
}
```

Is it possible to implement the above logic in C++ ?

Comment: `auto` needs to be resolved at compile time. There's no way out.

Comment: All types are determined, and checked, during compilation.

Comment: More to the point, `value` is one object so it has one type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auto` allows you to omit the type name and let the compiler deduce the type. There is no type to deduce from in your case, since there's no assignment, so nothing can be deduced.

For your use case, you need some kind of variant type that can store one of several types. The Qt library has `QVariant`, and other libraries usually offer something like that as well. As of C++17 however, such a type is offered directly by the standard library: [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

```
int usrId;
std::variant<bool, int> value;

if (isBool()) {
   value = fromStringtoBool();
} else {
   value = fromStringtoInt();
}

setAppidConfig(usrId, value);
```

The `setAppidConfig()` function would need to accept an appropriate `variant` parameter:

```
void setAppidConfig(int usrId, std::variant<bool, int> value)
{
    // ...

    if (std::holds_alternative<int>(value)) {
        // It's a int.
        int i = std::get<int>(value);
    } else {
        // It's a bool.
        bool b = std::get<bool>(value);
    }
}
```

Note that variants can hold more than just two types (you can have an `std::variant<bool, int, std::string>` for example.)

If you need something that can hold anything, then you can use an [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). This type does not need to know the types in advance (it takes no template arguments.)

Comment: All true, though the other solution presented is much simpler and more idiomatic/clear

Answer (score 3):

No. In C++ auto variable type resolution and also function overload resolution has to happen compile time. The `isBool()` of yours is presumably runtime value. So all you can do is something like:

```
if(isBool())
{
   setAppidConfig(usrId,fromStringtoBool());
}
else
{
   setAppidConfig(usrId,fromStringtoInt());
}
```

Comment: Actually, what my obsession is to call setAppidConfig() only once in C++11. There's no way out?

Comment: Your OP code has actually two setAppidConfig() functions with different types just name of those is same. In C++ you can not make the choice run-time what function with what parameters is called. Only virtual member functions can be chosen run-time in C++ and those have to have parameters of same type.